# How to test NumQueries in ListView?

Tags: python, django

I try to test my list view in Django 1.7:

```
class PostList(ListView):
    model = MyBlog
    template_name = 'posts.html'
    queryset = 'some_query'
    context_object_name = 'all_posts'
    paginate_by = 25

class BlogTests(TransactionTestCase):
    fixtures = ['blog.yaml']

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_posts_page(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse_lazy('blog'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200, 'incorrect http code in posts page')

    def test_posts_page_num_q(self):
        self.assertNumQueries(3, PostList.as_view())
```

But I have an error:

```
TypeError: view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

I have no idea, how to fix that.

Please, help.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace instead of just the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TestCase.assertNumQueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries) takes as a first argument the expected number of queries, as a second argument, the function you want to test and as the rest of the arguments, the arguments for the function you want to test.

In your case, the function you want to test is a view that requires one argument: an `HttpRequest`. You then need to pass an `HttpRequest` as a third parameter to `assertNumQueries`. You may use [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory) to create an `HttpRequest` for test purposes.